# Syntax error while using Foreign Keys in Sqlite 3 in Python.

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a database schema file which I read in my Flask module.

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;

drop table if exists user;
create table user(uid integer primary key autoincrement, 
username text not null,
password text not null,
email text not null);

drop table if exists asset;
create table asset(aid integer primary key autoincrement,
assetname text not null,
releasedate text,
FOREIGN_KEY(owner) REFERENCES user);
```

When I remove the foreign key field, it works fine.

Error trace:

```
  File "main.py", line 75, in <module>
    create_table()
  File "main.py", line 30, in create_table
    conn.cursor().executescript(f.read())
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

I can post the method which uses this script but I don't think the problem lies there.

Answer (score 1):

As @soon pointed you have a syntax error on `FOREIGN KEY` keyword, also you should define column name (owner).

`drop table if exists asset;
create table asset(aid integer primary key autoincrement,
assetname text not null,
releasedate text,
owner integer,
FOREIGN KEY(owner) REFERENCES user);`

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the underscore between the `FOREIGN` and `KEY` with a space. The following diagrams shows the constraint [syntax](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html):

[image]

And the [`foreign-key-clause`](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/foreign-key-clause.html) syntax is:

[image]